# When should I write a class instead of a group of functions?

Tags: python, mysql, class

I know some programming and I'm helping my father out by writing my first real application to his store. As I'm the only programmer, I have to make the decisions of how the program should be structured, and I'm really afraid of shooting my self in the foot with some of the "design choices".

One such problem I'm facing is when to use classes against just a bunch of methods. Let me give you a real example. I (will) have a bunch of functions that connect to a mysql db and parses the information in different ways. I know how classes work, I've read about them and implemented a bunch of example classes. But I have no idea when I should be using them instead of just a bunch of functions. I'd really appreciate if some more experienced programmers could share how the thought process behind this goes. Do you have any rule of thumb of when to write a class and when not to?

As a side question how much commenting is enough? As I never wrote any "real" programs I usually never commented my code. Now I can't help but feel like I'm over-commenting it because I'm afraid someday I'll get lost in my own code.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here's the code I have right now if anyone is curious, although it is not particularly relevant to the question.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb
import datetime as dt

try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database')
    cur = con.cursor()

except mdb.Error:
    print "Erro na conexao com o banco de dados!"
    exit()

def getAverageDate(date, question):
    """ Returns the average of ratings for a question in a given date
    "   Returns a Decimal object if the date exists in the
    "   database, otherwise, returns None
    """
    query = ("SELECT AVG(idvalue) FROM value, submissions "
            "WHERE value.answer = submissions.answer "
            "AND submissions.question_id = %s "
            "AND submissions.answer_date = %s")
    try:
        cur.execute(query, (question, date))
        result = cur.fetchone()[0]
        return result
    except mdb.Error:
        return mdb.Error;

def dateRange(initialDate, finalDate):
    """ Generates all dates between a range of dates, finalDate non inclusive"""
    for n in range(int ((finalDate - initialDate).days)):
        yield initialDate + dt.timedelta(n)

def getAverageBetweenDates(initialDate, finalDate, question):
    """ Returns a list containing two tuples with the average rating for
    "   a given date, and that date. If there are no ratings for a given
    "   date, it is not included in the list
    """
    dates = []
    values = []
    for date in dateRange(initialDate, finalDate):
        val = getAverageDate(date, question)
        if val is not None:
            dates.append(date.strftime("%x"))
            values.append(getAverageDate(date, question))
    return dates, values
```

Comment: Best recommendation I can give is to go the TDD (Test-Driven-Development) route. Then you can lean on the tests and refactor/restructure at will. Working code first, beautifully structured code second (*ducks*). Tests are both security and documentation.

Comment: I see. I'll take a look at Test Driven Development. Thank you very much!

Comment: TDD has nothing to do with this question. TDD should be done, yes; but it does not even resemble a possible answer to this question.

Comment: Hence why it was a comment not an answer ;) In my opinion for this project @AugustoDiasNoronha should _start_ and make sure he stays in a good position to change any major decisions. TDD is a good way to do this. I believe that an opinion as to object/procedural/functional will be given by a different helpful soul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Read about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. For starters the first principle is enough - the Single Responsibility Principle. Usually you don't leave loose, hanging methods. Rule of thumb is to build classes, that have one, precisely defined responsibility. You may define some utility functions (if you need them and Python doesn't provide them already), however you usually group them together in one separate module.

2) How much commenting is enough? That's an easy question - no comments at all should be enough. Code should document itself, by well-named classes and functions. Cool quotation:

> Code should read like well-written prose

The harder questions is - how much commenting is too much? Too much comments are when they can be replaced by better function/classes names and better partitioning of the code.

Comments as a means of explaining code are really just a historical left-over mechanism, when for example variables and functions needed to have short names. Nowadays you don't have to use "d" for a variable name, you can call it "invoiceDueDate" and use it conveniently. Using comments to document an API of a public library is IMHO the only good reason to use them.

Comment: Thank you for the SOLID link, it seems to explain exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

OK, apparently you at the moment only have a module with a few losely connected methods in it.

What is immediately noticeable is that you are creating a variable in the global context during loading of the module. This, to me, is a clear sign that you should use a class instead and put that code in the `__init__()` method:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb
import datetime as dt

class connector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database')
            self.cur = con.cursor()

        except mdb.Error:
            print "Erro na conexao com o banco de dados!"
            exit()

    # etc...
```

the all-important difference: `mdb.connect()` etc will not happen if you do `import connector` but when you initialize the class the first time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I can see that having control of when mdb.connect() happens is pretty important

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to plan on using classes for all your projects. In the long run it'll create a more solid structor, and you'll have a better overall grasp on the code. You'll have to think about each major aspect of your program, decide how you want them to interact with each other, what major components each will have, predict future events, and plan, always plan, for expansion. For example all the user functions (or methods) would go in an user class.

```
class user {
private:
     string name;
     int    age;

public:
     void setAge(int age);
     int getAge;
     void setName(string name);
     string getName();
}
```

That's C++, but concept stays true...

---

For the code you've shown, you could create a `db` (database) class. You could store any information returned (that's not being passed to another class object) in it's class variables, and all your functions would have a nice associated container to be called from.

Comment: I see. The general consesus seems to be that classes are the way to go for a number of reasons. Thank you for your answer